# Create a list of user-defined functions for vim?

Tags: php, vim, ide

So vim is pretty good about syntax highlighting. And I especially like how a function will change color, then I know I spelled it correct.

However, that is not the case for user-defined functions. I'm working with a large code base with many functions that are kind of long and I can't always remember the function name exactly.

Is there a way in vim to create a list of functions that will then be treated the standard library function (in terms of syntax highlighting)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's doable.. either that or emacs. what have you tried so far? vim does have a lot of customization

Comment: btw, i'm confused at this line  - `and I can't always remember the caps or exact term.`  - what caps ?

Comment: I haven't really tried much. I'm trying Google but I'm just finding stuff about defining vim functions.

Comment: I use GNU Global in emacs, I can put the lisp code in an answer if you're up for translating it into whatever vim understands.

Comment: There's a `gtags.vim` http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=893 but I'm not sure if it does the function highlighting out of the box like you're asking. Edit: Here's a similar idea that does the highlighting http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3114 I searched for `gtags vim highlighting` for reference.

Comment: If you use use tags you can complete via `<c-x><c-]>` to complete tags. See `:h ins-completion`

Answer (score 0):

- https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctlrp.vim
- https://github.com/tacahiroy/ctrlp-funky

Install both and type `:CtrlPFunky`

[image]

If you want to contains variables, global function, etc. Use `:CtrlPTag` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly looking for [Exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/).

Reference:

```
:help ins-completion
:help tags
:help ctags
```